# Python permutation code for list

Tags: python

i thought Python was candies :). 
i attempted my first problem and failed i'm suppose to do a "sort of permutation (not quite that")

```
L=[1,2,3]

for i in L[:-1]: 

    X=L[i:]+L[:i] 

    print(X)
```

the ouput should be

```
[1, 2, 3]

[2, 3, 1]

[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: forgive e if my answer is dumb. im VERY new to the language

Comment: Are you arranging the lists by index or value?

Comment: you can try this to get all permutation of list [1,2,3]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3]))

Comment: i dont want all the permutation. i just need to change this line appenrently; for i in L[:-1]

Comment: ok what about this .please be clear ..
for i in L:
 print(X)
 X=L[i:]+L[:i]

Comment: how much clear you want me to be? i included a test case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to do a rotation of the list. I don't really understand your above code but rotations are simple.

```
for i in L:
    print(L)
    L=L[1:]+L[:1]
```

This will rotate by one each time. Arbitrary rotations are also possible.

```
L=list(range(10))
n=3

for i in L:
    print(L)
    L=L[n:]+L[:n]
```

Use negatives for n in the opposite direction. One-liner:

```
print([L[n*i:]+L[:i*n] for i in range(len(L))])
```

To answer your question it will work as my one-liner, but no multiplication needed.

```
L=[1,2,3]

for i in range(len(L)): 
    X=L[i:]+L[:i]
    print(X)
```

But the way where you maintain state (the first way) is definitely preferred.

Comment: im only suppose to change the second line the for loop part

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. In that case it is the same as my one liner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this for a class then www.geeksforgeeks.org has a great one that explains it.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/
I made
    import sys
    # Python function to print permutations of a given list 
    def permutation(data):

```
    # If data is empty then there are no permutations 
    if len(data) == 0: 
        return [] 

    # If there is only one element in data then, only 
    # one permuatation is possible 
    if len(data) == 1: 
        return [data] 

    # Find the permutations for lst if there are 
    # more than 1 characters 

    l = [] # empty list that will store current permutation 

    # Iterate the input(data) and calculate the permutation 
    for i in range(len(data)): 
       m = data[i] 

       # Extract data[i] or m from the list.  remLst is 
       # remaining list 
       remLst = data[:i] + data[i+1:] 

       # Generating all permutations where m is first 
       # element 
       for p in permutation(remLst): 
           l.append([m] + p) 
    return l 


# Driver program to test above function 
#data = list('123') 
for p in permutation(list(sys.argv[1])): 
    print(p)
```

and do not forget that Python has built in function already.

```
from itertools import permutations 
l = list(permutations(range(1, 4))) 
print l
```